# C# wpf mediaelement play online video

Tags: c#, wpf

```
        student3.MediaFailed += MyMediaElement_MediaFailed;
        student3.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
        //change the mediaelement source to http://61.216.85.38:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8
        student3.Source = new Uri(@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Is it possible to play online video like http://61.216.85.38:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/playlist.m3u8
I already tried it but it always being black.
If the link is http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4, it can work.

Comment: It's incredibly hard to help someone who doesn't provide his code. We cannot see where / if you made any mistakes. Please show what you have tried and then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you're trying to set `MediaElement.Source` directly to playlist's URI, the answer is "no": `MediaElement` can't play playlists directly.

You need to download playlist, parse its content, and implement your own logic to play content from playlist (e.g., from first to last, or randomly).

Comment: Well, if you will post some code, which is not working, it will be much easier to help you.